# Phonegap storage transaction callback called several times

Tags: database, transactions, callback, cordova, indexeddb

I'm developing a Phonegap 2.5 application with local storage, using transactions to perform database operations. Trouble is, every once in a while, the application gets into a state where the transaction callbacks are called more than once for the same transaction. This is an example of how i perform the transaction (when the save function of DbAccess is called):

```
function DbAccess(db)
{
    this.db = db;

    this.save = function(data, callback)
    {
        alert('saving'); //called once
        this.db.transaction(function(tx){

            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE ...');
            tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM ...');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ...');

        }, function(error){ 
               //on error
               callback({
               "success" : false
               });
        }, function(){
               //on successs
               callback({
               "success" : true
               });
        });
    }
}
```

When the application gets into this state, the callback function gets called several times (through the error on success callback functions),
although the save function is only called once (alert only pops up once). 
I suspect these errors appear when the application creates more than one database.
I create a database whose name is based on the username used to log in to the application (username and instance variables are user inputs):

```
var dbName = username + '_' + instance;
var db = window.openDatabase(dbName, "1.0", "OfflineData", 1000000);
```

If i delete the application data and launch again, the problems stop.
I'm at a loss as to why this happens, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Corrected your tags as this is IndexedDB and not localStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is websql, not IndexedDB.

Your finding seems like a bug on phonegap.

Try listening error and success callbacks on `executeSql`. Execute your three steps in order by listening success callbacks. It should fix the problem.

Multiple databases should be fine.

Comment: Event after upgrading Phonegap to version 2.9 the behaviour persists, however, it seems your solution manages to patch the problem, thank you.